# Admin submenu issue with PHP not detecting two strings as equal

Tags: php, admin-menu, core

I am adding a submenu page as follows:

```
add_submenu_page( $slug, __('Categories','acs'), __('Categories','acs'), $cap, 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&post_type=acs-field-group' );
```

But the submenu does not display as active when selected.

So after wondering... I went into WP Core and added a var dump at **wp-amdin/menu-header.php**

Right where the check is made, to add the *.current* CSS classname.

```
var_dump($submenu_file);
var_dump($sub_item[2]);
```

And... the output is a mystery:

```
string(77) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&post_type=acs-field-group"
string(73) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&post_type=acs-field-group"
```

Same string, different length!

Of course it must be some encoding game, but I'm using phpStorm with encoding set to UTF-8.

I don't know how to get over this, help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> string(77) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&post_type=acs-field-group"
> string(73) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&post_type=acs-field-group"
> ```
>
> Same string, different length!

**No, they're not the same string** — if you had viewed the raw/server-generated HTML source, or used this instead of the `var_dump($submenu_file);`:

```php
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($submenu_file, $sub_item[2]); echo '</pre>';
```

Then you would have seen the correct string which uses `&amp;` instead of just `&`:

```php
string(77) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&amp;post_type=acs-field-group"
```

So that means, **your (sub-)menu slug (the 5th parameter for [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)) needs to use the ampersand's HTML entity, i.e. `&amp;`**, like so:

```php
add_submenu_page( $slug, __('Categories','acs'), __('Categories','acs'), $cap, // wrapped for brevity
    'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=acs-field-group-category&amp;post_type=acs-field-group' ); // ← use &amp;
```

That way, the submenu would be active when the submenu page is loaded.

And actually, you can see a core example [here in `wp-admin/edit-tags.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4c265b66297074f09d66c17d9f14d11a5fffdb00/wp-admin/edit-tags.php#L48) (WordPress v6.0.1), which implies that `$submenu_file` (the submenu slug) expects `&amp;` to be used.

<sub>PS: Remember to restore the original `wp-admin/menu-header.php file` — remove your "hack"/modifications.</sub>

Comment: I have to thank you for this. Always thought that `var_dump()` is the correct way to dump a var's info. Using the `<pre>` tag to avoid losing special information is something new I learn today.

Comment: You're welcome, and actually, you could just use the [`submenu_file` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/submenu_file/) (along with `error_log()`) to [debug](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) the submenu file that's used on the current page. You could also use it (and the [`parent_file` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parent_file/)) to change the submenu that would be highlighted on that page.

Comment: A million thanks! :)